# PHP coding a button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, button

I need help figuring out what is wrong with my code for this button I have. Can anyone please tell me what I have done wrong? I am new to this.

```
echo '<td><button class="sub_btn" value="Book now" onclick="var f = document.getElementById("form");
        f.action="bookevents.php?id=<?php=$row["event_id"] ?> f.submit()"></button></td>';
```

Comment: You could start by telling us what is the problem you are facing. For instance: I want to obtain xxx, but my code gives me yyy.

Comment: I need to get the event id so that it is placed in the browsers search bar. There is multiple events that is why I have written it the way I have. What it does right now is display f.submit() in the button.

Comment: If you view your source in your browser, you'll see the PHP tags have been rendered, stopping the onclick event from taking the correct string value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are using a php Tag in PHP.

And I think you're missing `;` in your javascript part, as I can see it so far.

And at your `document.getElementByID` part you will close your `onclick`. Fixed this, too.

You can try this:

```
echo '<td><button class="sub_btn" value="Book now" onclick="var f = document.getElementById(\'form\');
        f.action="bookevents.php?id='.$row["event_id"].'; f.submit();"></button></td>';
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: event_id in E:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\FlexiFlash Outcome 01\Booking system\events.php on line 70

Comment: Well that's an error that has nothing to do with this code snippet. Check where you define $row and if you have event_id index of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already in PHP, you don't need to include `<?php` and `?>` in your echo. Try:

```
echo '<td><button class="sub_btn" value="Book now" onclick="var f = document.getElementById("form");f.action="bookevents.php?id=' . $row["event_id"] . ' f.submit()"></button></td>';
```